# How to access `String`s at a given `Index` concisely?

Tags: swift, string, indexing, swift3

In Swift 3 [SE-0065](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) changed the indexing model for `Collection`s, wherein responsibility for index traversal is moved from the index to the collection itself. For example, instead of writing `i.successor()`, onehas to write `c.index(after: i)`.

What this means in terms of accessing `String`s at a certain index, is that instead of writing this:

```
let aStringName = "Bar Baz"
aStringName[aStringName.startIndex.advancedBy(3)]
```

...we now have to write this:

```
aStringName[aStringName.index(aStringName.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)]
```

This seems incredibly redundant, as `aStringName` is mentioned thrice. So my question is if there's any way to get around this (aside from writing an extension to `String`)?

Comment: I believe this very point was lifted as one of the disadvantages of the SE-0065 proposal, however somewhat redeemed by the fact that in many applications the collection `aStringName` could be referred to by `self` and in many applications, hence omitted.

Comment: `Array(s.characters)[3]` would be concise, but ineffective for long strings. `s.characters.dropFirst(3).first` is an alternative, but not really more nice. – Often you need the characters sequentially, and then you should *enumerate* them instead of indexing repeatedly.

Comment: @MartinR does the `enumerated()` method produce a lazy sequence for `String`s? Because otherwise it seems quite expensive to enumerate the characters.

Comment: I am fairly sure that enumerated() produces a lazy sequence, and effectively yields all characters.

Comment: I have long ago got fed up of Swift's string access model. Most of the time, I can care less about "extended grapheme cluster"  and just want to get the n-th character of a string. So I just extend `String` to add a subscript by `Int`

Comment: @CodeDifferent Yeah, that's what I ended up doing now, too :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future Googlers, I'm posting my `String` extension below. It allows you to access a string with `Int`s rather than the cumbersome `Index`:

```
extension String {
    subscript(index: Int) -> Character {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
        return self[startIndex]
    }

    subscript(range: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.count)
        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }

    subscript(range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.count)
        return self[startIndex...endIndex]
    }

    subscript(range: NSRange) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.length)
        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
}

let str = "Hello world"

print(str[0])                   // Get the first character
print(str[0..<5])               // Get characters 0 - 4, with a CountableRange
print(str[0...4])               // Get chacraters 0 - 4, with a ClosedCountableRange
print(str[NSMakeRange(0, 5)])   // For interacting with Foundation classes, such as NSRegularExpression
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no neat or concise way to do this without writing an extension. A version of such an extension could look like this:

```
extension String {
  subscript(offset offset: Int) -> Character {
    return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
  }
}
```