# In swift 3, how do you advance an index?

Tags: ios, swift

I've trying to get a substring of a string starting from index 1 in iOS 10 beta 6, and its a headache as swifts strings are constantly changing and much documentation is out of date and useless.

String has the substring(from:Index), but it can't accept an integer (which has been the case for a while), so I was planning to use startIndex and advance it by 1, but now Index has no advanceBy method, so I cannot do this:

```
let aString = "hello"
let subString = aString.substring(from: aString.startIndex.advanceBy(1))
```

How can I get a substring from index 1? How can you advance an index these days,  and what is the point of the substring(from Index) method - how are you supposed to use it?

Comment: I'm tired at Swift's string model too so I wrote my own extension. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38939327/2538939

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38215613/2303865

Comment: @Leo Dabus. The accepted answer in your link has startIndex.advancedBy(). But as I've pointed out, advanceBy is no longer there in 10.6

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated you can try the one I posted beta 2 probably works with beta 6

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks pretty clear as the first item in the [Swift 3 migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/):

> The most visible change is that indexes no longer have `successor()`, `predecessor()`, `advancedBy(_:)`, `advancedBy(_:limit:)`, or `distanceTo(_:)` methods. Instead, those operations are moved to the collection, which is now responsible for incrementing and decrementing its indices.
>
> ```
> myIndex.successor()  =>  myCollection.index(after: myIndex)
> myIndex.predecessor()  =>  myCollection.index(before: myIndex)
> myIndex.advance(by: …) => myCollection.index(myIndex, offsetBy: …)
> ```

So it looks like you want something like:

```
let greeting = "hello"
let secondCharIndex = greeting.index(after: greeting.startIndex)
let enryTheEighthGreeting = greeting.substring(from: secondCharIndex) // -> "ello"
```

(Note also that if you want `Collection` functionality—like index management—on a `String`, it sometimes helps to use its [`characters`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540072-characters) view. `String` methods like `startIndex` and `index(after:)` are just conveniences that forward to the `characters` view. That part isn't new, though... `String`s stopped being `Collection`s themselves in Swift 2 IIRC.)

There's more about the collection indexes change in [SE-0065 - A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540072-characters).

Answer (score 9):

#### Swift 3:

```
let str = "hello"
let subStr = str.substring(from:str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
print(subStr) // ello
```

**Less verbose solution:**

```
let index:Int = 1
let str = "hello"
print(str.substring(from: str.idx(index))) // ello
extension String{
    func idx(_ index:Int) -> String.Index{
        return self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index)
    }
}
```